# js animating block with image inside

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

Have a block with another relative block inside, which has a background in style of parent block (like on a a picture). When i trying to change width of my block, relative block disappears.

[picture](http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/12/0828/h_1346148569_9296399_c500fa8e0e.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<style>
 #button
{
    width: 195px ;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: url('/res/bg.png') repeat-x;
}
#button div#arrow
{
    background: url('/res/Arrow.png') no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: -30px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='button'>
<div id='arrow'></div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Forgot about the code of animating:
$('#button').animate({width:'-=120px'}, 2000)

Comment: does it disappear on every browser? could you provide a demo page?

Comment: Added a js string, which i use for animating, i tried it only in chrome in js console

Comment: You could put two divs on top of each other, one with the gradient background at the bottom, and on with the arrow on the top, and position the arrow background to the right (background-position:right;). Seems less error prone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow: visible !important` on the parent `div`.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P5CHX/2/